# Using Reflection to get BaseType Class DeclaredFields

Tags: c#, system.reflection

I see lots of similar questions regarding reflection, but not exactly what I'm looking for.  I am calling a dll at runtime using Assembly.LoadFile().  Once I have loaded the dll, I need to retrieve a class, then all of its Base class property values (that are preset in that dll code).  I thought I was close, but I'm missing how to cast, or maybe I am completely wrong.

I'm trying to retrieve the class highlighted in the picture below
[image: Trying to get the class out of the highlighted line]

```
            //This is really all I have thus far
            var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);
            var primaryInterface = assembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "VpInterface");
            //This is wrong, not giving me expected fields
            var features = ((System.Reflection.TypeInfo)primaryInterface.BaseType.GetField("Features").GetType())
                .DeclaredFields;


//Part of the class I am trying to retrieve
public class IntegratorFeatures
{
    public string Registration { get; set; }
    public string DefaultPort { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryInterface { get; set; }
    public string LiveCaptureType { get; set; }
    public string CapturedStreamType { get; set; }
    public int PtzFeatures { get; set; }
    //etc, about 20 more properties after this
```

I'm not real familiar with Reflection for such advanced tasks.  Once I have the above issue coded, I then have to figure out how to call methods within each of the classes in the dll.  But I somehow suspect that will be easier than this initial call (hopefully that is a correct assumption)

Thanks in advance for the assistance

Comment: `GetField("Features").GetType()` is getting the type info for `FieldInfo`. You want the `FieldType` property instead. You're chaining too much together to see it clearly.

Comment: How do i get the FieldType instead?

Comment: `GetField("Features").FieldType`

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  This code works, returning the desired base class I was looking for:

```
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(dllFile);
        var intPtr = new IntPtr(1);
        var primaryInterface = assembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "VpInterface");
        var baseInt = new BaseInterface(intPtr);
        var features = 
            (IntegratorFeatures)primaryInterface.BaseType
                .GetField("Features", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .GetValue(baseInt);
```

My original understanding of how GetValue worked, was that I was getting an instance of the desired class.  But it seems to need to match the instance I am getting in Reflection, which is actually the base class itself, which contains the desired class.  Still a bit confusing to me, but at least it gets the properties I need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public List<System.Reflection.PropertyInfo> GetFields(string AssemblyFilePath)
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(AssemblyFilePath).GetTypes().First(x => x.Name == "The class name you want to get the fields for.").GetProperties().ToList();
    }
```

This will return a list of PropertyInfos which, can be used to find the name of the property.

Comment: This didn't work for me.  I think part of the problem is that I am trying to get properties that are defined in the Inherited Base Class.

This code comes really close, but I haven't yet figured out what to exactly use as the parameter in GetValue

var objType = typeof(BaseInterface);
var primaryInterface = assembly.DefinedTypes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "VpInterface");
var feature1a = primaryInterface.BaseType.GetField("Features").GetValue(objType);